# How to use google developer tool to analyze website

Tags: json, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract data from a website using css (and parse html) but for some website the url doesn't return the html so I need to find the url that return json but I don't how can do this.

Here some website

https://egovjesolo.jentecloud.net/jalbopretorio/AlboPretorio
https://www.comune.roma.it/gedalbonet/albo/listaatti

Someone can help me ?

thx

Francesco

I tried to use css but for these website's the html not contains the info present in the webpage

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.